# How to check if a channel is empty

Tags: django, django-channels, channel

In Channels 1 I could get the number of pending messages in a channel with:

```
RedisChannelLayer().channel_statistics(channel_name).get("messages_pending")
```

I used this during automatic tests to ensure that the channel is empty before starting the next test to avoid an undesired influence of old channel messages.

How can I check if a channel is empty or get the number of pending messages in a channel in Channels 2?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I couldn't solve it so far. A workaround is to read out the values directly from redis-cli and check there are none.